# get_the_post_thumbnail_url() in portfolio plugin return wrong url

Tags: plugins, background, shortcode

I've developed a plugin to create a portfolio custom post type and to do display a preview of the last 3 post published with a shortcode.

Everything is fine and it's work, the only problem is that when I want to display with the shortcode the post's thumbnail as background image of the post's preview it not appear and the image url is displayed like this, without the slashes:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-5 portfolio-panel" id="porfolio-home-display" style="background-image: url(" https:="" sitedomain.com="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2021="" 10="" image-name.jpg");"=""><h5><a href="link">Link name</a></h5><a href="link">See this work</a></div>
```

Here i place the part of code relative to the shortcode:

```
function wpb_rand_portfolio() {
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby'   => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 3, 
        );
     
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        
    $string .= '<div class="container portfolio-panel-homecontainer">';
    $string .= '<div class="row portfolio-panel-homebox squares">'; 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $string .= '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-5 portfolio-panel" id="porfolio-home-display" style="background-image: url("'. get_the_post_thumbnail_url() .'");">';
        $string .= '<h5><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h5>';
        $string .= '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. sprintf( __( 'See this work', 'theme-name' )) .'</a>';
        $string .= '</div>';
    }
    $string .= '</div>';
        $string .= '</div>';
    $string .= '</div>';
    // Restore original Post Data 
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    } else {
    
    $string .= '<div class="container portfolio-panel-homecontainer">';
    $string .= '<div class="row portfolio-panel-homebox squares">'; 
    $string .= '<div class="col-12">';  
    $string .= 'no posts found';
    $string .= '</div>';
    $string .= '</div>';
    $string .= '</div>';
    
    }
     
    return $string; 
    
    } 
 
add_shortcode('wpb-random-portfolio','wpb_rand_portfolio');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

I've searched on the site but I haven't found any solution. Can you help me?

Thank to everyone